# Three.js 3D model position

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to adjust the position of the model?
When the scene is created, the model does not land on the plane as the photo shows.
I want it to position itself in the middle on the plan.

Model position

[image: 1]

```js
public async createScene(canvas: ElementRef < HTMLCanvasElement > ) {
  console.log('create scene function');
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.loadingMessage = 'Creating the scene';
  }, 100);

  this.isErrorHappened = false;
  this.canvas = canvas.nativeElement;

  this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: this.canvas,
    alpha: true,
    antialias: true
  });
  this.renderer.setSize(this.size.width, this.size.height);
  this.renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));

  this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
  this.scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);

  this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  this.camera.position.x = -25;
  this.camera.position.y = 15;
  this.camera.position.z = 0;

  this.ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(this.lightColor, 0.5);
  this.scene.add(this.ambientLight);

  this.directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(this.lightColor, 1);
  this.directionalLight.position.set(0, 10, 0);
  this.directionalLight.target.position.set(-5, 0, 0);
  this.scene.add(this.directionalLight);
  this.scene.add(this.directionalLight.target);

  this.gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(50, 30);
  this.scene.add(this.gridHelper);
  this.axes = new THREE.AxesHelper(20);
  this.axes.renderOrder = 1;
  this.scene.add(this.axes);
  this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.canvas);
}
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask] and take the [tour]. Note that "does anybody know?" isn't a good question. Instead, just ask what you want to know.

Comment: You add lights, a grid and axes to your scene. Please show the code where you actually add the model, because that's where you can set its position.

Comment: Btw, you can set the position like so: `myObject.position.set(x, y, z);`. See https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D

Comment: this.createScene(this.rendererCanvas).then(() => { this.loadIFC(this.ifcurl).then(() => this.animate()) });

Here is the code that loads the model

Answer (score 0):

Just move the position of the object to the origin?

```
myObject.position.set(0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, IFC.js locates the model in the position specified in the IFC file. This means that the position of that file is probably wrong.

IFC.js also provides a method to ignore this and just place the model in the center, while storing the original transform of the model: `ifcLoader.ifcManager.applyWebIfcConfig()`. [Here](https://ifcjs.github.io/info/docs/Guide/web-ifc-three/api#applywebifcconfig) you have a link to the official docs. You can use it like this:

```
await ifcLoader.ifcManager.applyWebIfcConfig({
   COORDINATE_TO_ORIGIN: true
});
```